# How to run a shell script in SVN from "Execute Shell" in Jenkins?

Tags: bash, shell, jenkins, svn

I have a shell script called restart_server.sh stored in SVN. I have set up a new job in Jenkins with SVN configuration and the command in "Execute Shell" is  *bash -ex restart-server.sh*

However when I do a build, I get the below error. Any ideas on what I am missing?

````
FATAL: command execution failed
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "sh" (in directory "E:\project\jenkins\workspace\Restart_Server_Shell"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1041)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:244)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:216)
    at hudson.Launcher$LocalLauncher.launch(Launcher.java:780)
    at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.start(Launcher.java:360)
    at hudson.tasks.CommandInterpreter.perform(CommandInterpreter.java:97)
    at hudson.tasks.CommandInterpreter.perform(CommandInterpreter.java:66)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:772)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:199)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:160)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:535)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1732)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:234)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:385)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:136)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1022)
    ... 15 more
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE```
````

Comment: It sounds like the script is a Linux script (`bash...`) but your jenkins instance is running on Windows (`in directory "E:\project\...`). That's not going to work. Is there a Windows-compatible script in your project? Or can you use a Linux-based jenkins instance?

Comment: Yes, it is running in Windows instance. There is no Linux based instance. Just figured out that I have to use sshexec